# Origin of the inspiration behind the titular character in The Bat, a play by Mary Roberts Rinehart and Avery Hopwood

Tags: inspiration, mary-roberts-rinehart, the-bat

What was the inspiration for *The Bat*, the titular character from [Mary Roberts Rinehart's play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bat_(play)) (later adapted into [a movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bat_(1926_film)))? The character originally appeared in the play which was adapted from the novel *The Circular Staircase*. The Bat didn't appear in the novel, he was an original character for the play.

He partially inspired Batman through the later movie *[The Bat Whispers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bat_Whispers)*.

What was the inspiration for the character?

Comment: We can be fairly confident that it was a bat. But _which_ bat?